# Python find index of list of list, but only at specific index of internal list

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I have a list of lists in the format:

```
list = [["5:2", "1:0"],["3:4", "5:2"],["1:2", "1:1"],["4:5", "1:0"]]
```

I would like to check if the first index of each internal lists contains a string.
I have tried to use the following:

```
(next(i for i,j in enumerate(list) if (a) in j))
```

However, this checks every string in the list of lists, instead of a specific index.

How could I modify this code to only check index 0 of the internal list?

Thanks

Comment: `if a in j[0]`? since `j` would be, for example, `["6:2", "1:0"]`

Comment: `all(isinstance(i[0], str) for i in list)`…?

Comment: Try `ans = [i for i, j in enumerate(list) if type(j[0]) == str]`, this makes a list of all indices with the 0th element as a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1. If you want all the list elements' indices that have the first element as a string:

```
ans = [i for i, j in enumerate(list) if type(j[0]) == str]
```

2. If you want a boolean output list:

```
ans = [True if type(i[0]) == str else False for i in list]
```

Answer (score 0):

use `isinstance`:

```
for item in my_list:
    if isinstance(item[0], str):
        print("True!")
```

`my_list` since you should not name your lists `list`.

Comment: cheers, ended up using the solution mentioned in a previous comment. and yeah, I was only using list as a name of a list as an example.